# Mapping two rows to one row in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `a` with 14 rows and another dataframe `comp1sum` with 7 rows. `a` has date column for 7 days in 12hr interval. So that makes it 14 rows. Also, `comp1sum` has a column with 7 days.

This is the `comp1sum` dataframe

[image: dataframe comp1sum]

And this is the `a` dataframe

[image: a dataframe]

I want to map 2 rows of `a` dataframe to single rows of `comp1sum` dataframe. So, that one day of dataframe `a` is mapped to one day of `comp1sum` dataframe.

I have the following code for that

```
j=0
for i in range(0,7):
    a.loc[i,'comp1_sum'] = comp_sum.iloc[j]['comp1sum']
    a.loc[i,'comp2_sum'] = comp_sum.iloc[j]['comp2sum']
    j=j+1
```

And its output is

```
      dt_truncated         comp1_sum
3   2015-02-01 00:00:00     142.0
10  2015-02-01 12:00:00     144.0
12  2015-02-03 00:00:00     145.0
2   2015-02-05 00:00:00     141.0
14  2015-02-05 12:00:00     NaN
```

The code is mapping the days from `comp1sum` based on index of `a` and not based on dates of `a`. I want `2015-02-01 00:00:00` to have the values `139.0` and `2015-02-02 00:00:00` to have the value 140.0 and so on such that increasing dates have increasing values.

I am not able to map in such a way. please help.

---

Edit1- As per @Ssayan answer, I am getting this error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-77e55efca5f9> in <module>
      3 # use the sorted index to iterate through the sorted dataframe
      4 for i, idx in enumerate(a.index):
----> 5     a.loc[idx, 'comp1_sum'] = b.iloc[i//2]['comp1sum']
      6     a.loc[idx,'comp2_sum'] = b.iloc[i//2]['comp2sum']

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your DataFrame `a` is not sorted by date so the index 0 does not match the earliest date. When you use `loc` it uses the value of the index, not the order in which the table is, so even with sorting the DataFrame the issue remains.

One way out is to sort the DataFrame `a` by date and then to use the sorted index to apply the value in the order you need.

```py
# sort the dataframe by date
a = a.sort_values("dt_truncated")
# use the sorted index to iterate through the sorted dataframe
for i, idx in enumerate(a.index):
    a.loc[idx, 'val_1'] = b.iloc[i//2]['val1']
    a.loc[idx,'val_2'] = b.iloc[i//2]['val2']
```

Comment: with this code I am getting an error `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` I have updated it in the question. Check the last part.

Comment: With reference to the `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`, there were 15 indexes in my `a` dataframe and 7 in `b` hence I reduced indexes in dataframe `a` to 14.

Comment: can you please upvote the question :) Thanks

Comment: Yes my solution works only for an even number on the DataFrame matching half of this number in the second DataFrame. Cases outside of this needs to be managed in the loop depending on what behaviour you expect.